# how can I format x-axis date to show month-name on the start of every month, then day numbers only?

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, seaborn

I have the below python code, it returns no x-axis labels. How can I format the x-axis to show month names at the start of every month and then day numbers afterwards?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 10))

boxProp = dict(ls='-', 
               lw=0.50, 
               color='darkgoldenrod', 
               edgecolor = '#3a5e42', 
               facecolor = 'white')

fliProp = dict(color = '#3a5e42', 
               marker = '8',
               mec = '#3a5e42',
               mew = 2,
               mfc = 'white',
               ms = 2)

whisProp = dict(color = '#3a5e42', lw=0.50)

capProp = dict(color = '#3a5e42', lw=0.50)

medProps = dict(color = '#3a5e42')


boxplot = sns.boxplot(ax=axs, 
                      x = HistPrices.index.date,
                      y = HistPrices.values, 
                      color = 'white',
                      width = 0.8,
                      boxprops = boxProp,
                      whiskerprops = whisProp,
                      capprops = capProp,
                      medianprops = medProps,
                      flierprops = fliProp)



axs.tick_params(direction='out', which='major', length=8, width=1)
axs.tick_params(direction='out', which='minor', length=4, width=1)


day_fmt = DateFormatter('%d')
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator( DayLocator() )
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(day_fmt)
 

axs.yaxis.set_major_locator( MultipleLocator(0.5) )
axs.yaxis.set_minor_locator( MultipleLocator(0.1) )
```

HistPrices.index.date returns the below:

array([datetime.date(2021, 1, 4), datetime.date(2021, 1,4),...,datetime.date(2021, 7, 22)], dtype=object)

Answer (score 0):

I think concise date formatter does exactly what you are asking:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html